# tsql multipe update on single table

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is there a way to update a table based on multiple where clause. In one single statement?

```
update A
set Final = '21'
from StudentTable A
where Student_ID= 4 and bitcm= 0 and receipt= 17



update B
set Final = '22'
from StudentTable B
where Student_ID=4 and bitcm= 0 and receipt =12


update C
set Final ='11'
from StudentTable C
where Student_ID=4 and bitcmp=1 and receipt=17


update D
set Final ='12'
from StudentTable D
where Student_ID=4 and bitcmp=1 and receipt=12
```

Is there a way to combine all this statement into a single statement?

Comment: Yes. The best approach depends - are there any other rows for `Student_ID` 4, other than the 4 you've shown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
UPDATE  A
SET     Final = CASE WHEN bitchcm = 0 AND receipt = 17 THEN '21'
                     WHEN bitchcm = 0 AND receipt = 12 THEN '22'
                     WHEN bitchcm = 1 AND receipt = 17 THEN '11'
                     WHEN bitchcm = 1 AND receipt = 12 THEN '12'
                END
FROM    StudentTable A
WHERE   Student_ID = 4 AND   -- the purpose of the three conditions
        bitcm IN (0,1) AND   -- is to speed up the query. It will not
        receipt IN (12,17)   -- scan the whole records on the table
```

If column `FINAL` is `INT` then you don't need to wrap the values with single quotes.

Comment: @ypercube is this the one I'd ask for an example? thanks `:D`

Comment: Altough your proposition is correct for this specific case, the whole approach is wrong. If one decides to remove the last update, he'd also remove the last WHEN statement. But WHERE clause stays the same and still matches those records that we decided not to update. And CASE result for them will be.. NULL

Comment: @frikozoid if he decides to remove one of the updates, he should update his query. This approach is 100% correct. It's not JW's job to plan for future changes to a query that weren't even mentioned.

Comment: @JW. Yes, check the results. Can you spot the problem?

Comment: @frikozoid if that's the case then what will be the best update statement on this problem?

Answer (score 3):

If those are the only four rows for `Student_ID` 4, then the following works:

```
update A
set Final = CASE
    WHEN bitcm=0 and receipt=17 THEN '21'
    WHEN bitcm= 0 and receipt =12 THEN '22'
    WHEN bitcmp=1 and receipt=17 THEN '11'
    WHEN bitcmp=1 and receipt=12 THEN '12'
    END
from StudentTable A
where Student_ID= 4
```

(I assume `bitcm` and `bitcmp` are meant to be the same column, but I'm not sure which spelling to use)

A more general approach would be to have a table (table variable or parameter, probably) containing all required key columns and the new Final value. You'd then write:

```
UPDATE A
SET Final = B.Final
FROM StudentTable A
INNER JOIN @AboveMentionedTableVariableOrParameter B
ON
    A.Student_ID = B.Student_ID and
    A.bitcm = b.bitcm and
    A.receipt = b.receipt --And add any other necessary conditions here.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a CASE Statement

```
UPDATE StudentTable
SET Final = 
 CASE WHEN Student_ID= 4 and bitcm= 0 and receipt= 17 THEN 21
  WHEN Student_ID=4 and bitcm= 0 and receipt =12 THEN 22
  WHEN Student_ID=4 and bitcmp=1 and receipt=17 THEN 11
  WHEN Student_ID=4 and bitcmp=1 and receipt=12 THEN 12
 END
WHERE Student_ID = 4
AND bitcm IN (0,1)
AND receipt IN (12,17)
```